# How to avoid that the GoogleMap change the camera twice?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-api

this is my first question here:

I'm developing an Android app using Google Maps API and in my main activity I have a fragment with the map. I center the map with the moveCamera method within the event onMapLoaded but the problem is that while the map is loading, it displays the Ecuador and then it switchs to the area I have chosen.

How can I avoid this? I can't invoke moveCamera() outside the event onMapLoaded

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep track of the camera position, you can use an `OnCameraChangeListener` 
which is set on the map by calling GoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(OnCameraChangeListener).

The listener will be notified when the camera changes with an `onCameraChange(CameraPosition)` callback. You can then obtain the target (latitude/longitude), zoom, bearing and tilt of the camera. This `callback` is guaranteed to be called at the end of every animation but may not be called for intermediate frames.